# Find the limit function $f$ of $\{F_n\}$. $F_n=nx^n(1-x^2) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

> Find the limit function $f$ of $\{F_n\}$. $F_n=nx^n(1-x^2) $

My solution:

For $x=\pm1, 0, F_n=0 \implies f(0)=f(1)=f(-1)=0$.

For $|x|>0$. we have
$$(1-x^2)\lim_{n\to\infty} nx^n=\infty\text{ , if }x>1$$

and $$(1-x^2)\lim_{n\to\infty} nx^n=-1^n\infty\text{ if }x<-1$$

Finally, for $0<|x|< 1,$ we have
$$(1-x^2)\lim_{n\to\infty} nx^n= (1-x^2)\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{-nx^{-n-1}}== -(1-x^2)\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n}=0$$

Hence {F_n} converges pointwise to $f=0$ on the interval $[-1,1]$

Comment: That's ok. Depending on who is asking, they might want (or not) some little clarification regarding the last limit (since $n\to \infty$ but $x^n \to 0$.)

Comment: @Alejandro Nasif Salum I edited my solution.

Comment: Well... now I don't get it... Why is $n$ in the denominator and what did you do?

Comment: @Alejandro Nasif Salum I used L'Hopital rule

Comment: Ok. Now I get it. You took derivatives on $x$, but the limit is on $n$. If you were to use L'H rule you should take derivatives with respect to $n$; anyway, here $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so you should actually think of it as differentiable function of $n\in \mathbb{R}$ (maybe changing its name to make it look more natural; but the derivative would still be with respect to that variable.)

Comment: Remember you have a sequence here. If it's easier, think of a particular value of $x$ (with $|x|<1$), maybe $n\left(\tfrac12\right)^n$. How do you prove it tends to zero?